# What are the differences between APIs, Libraries, Packages and Frameworks?

Tags: javascript, api, npm, package, frameworks

On my way of learning web development, I very often listen to theses words:

- **APIs**
- **Libraries**
- **Packages**
- **Frameworks**

They all seem to be pre-builded tools.

Please help me understand the differences between them.
Thanks!

Comment: Easier to google all these separately. Here is not really the place to ask such high level questions. All 4 topics are not hard to grasp but needs some patience.

Comment: Of course i have browse those words separalely, but answers are always ambigous and superficials

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.